# Count number of img tags inside a div tag

Tags: jquery

My code goes like this.

```
<div id="some_id">
    <img src="some_image.png">
    <img src="some_image.png">
    <div class="another_div"></div>
    <div class="another_div"></div>
</div>
```

I want to count number of img tags inside that div element.

I found this from a similar question on stackoverflow which returns count of all the children.

```
var count = $("#some_id").children().length;
```

How do I modify this code or use some other function to count the number of img tags inside the div?

Comment: $('#some_id img').length

Comment: Really? You don't try anything or read some basic tutorials?!

Comment: Those downvotes are a bit unfair...

Comment: And whoever is voting to close as off-topic... seriously :(

Comment: @Ben  <<Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist>>  Seems clear enough, isn't it?!

Comment: @roasted `var count = $("#some_id").children().length;` looks like an both a minimum understanding and attempt to me. The question isn't lazy either, it's asked pretty clearly.

Comment: @Ben Couldn't OP check in DOC for children method? If so, he would have find that:  `var count = $("#some_id").children('img').length;`

Comment: @roasted. Do everyone need to be an expert at a topic before asking a question or am I missing the whole point of this place?

Comment: @Ben You don't have to be expert to read DOC, do you? That's ok, you give your point of view, i give mine.

Comment: @roasted - Making me feel guilty for asking the question. :'(

Comment: @aBhijit Sorry for that, but please try something on your side next time  ;) Using selector is basic and this kind of question has been asked thousand times before, hope you understand my point of view. Have a good day!

Comment: Sure. Good day to you too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Count img inside #some_div:

```
 $("#some_id img").length
```

If you want only the direct children, not all descendants:

```
$("#some_id > img").length
```

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
var count = $("#some_id").find('img').length;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var count = $("#some_id img").length
```

Select the image tags like this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var count = $('#some_id').find('img').length;
```

Answer (score 4):

Or the plain version without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("some_id").getElementsByTagName("img").length
```

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
$("#some_id img").length
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to get them like this:

```
var count = $("#some_id img").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("#some_id img").length
```

[Here's a fiddle of it.](http://jsfiddle.net/r89KL/)

Answer (score 1):

Also (even though there are many right answers here), every of these methods in jQuery, such as **children()**, **siblings()**, **parents()**, **closest()**, etc. accept a jQuery selector as a parameter.

So doing

`$("#some_id").children("img").length`

should return what you need as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = $("#some_id img").length;
```

It will give you total length of images inside a div.