# jQuery .length not applying the right classes to ACF Repeater fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, class, advanced-custom-fields

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I am using a ACF repeater field to create dynamic rows. I then use jQuery to assign a unique classes to each row for example:

```
$('.section').each(function(i) {
   $(this).addClass('section' + (i + 1));
});
```

This gives me the classes `<div class="row section section1">` etc. However I then need to look inside the row and add a column around each image for example span_12 for one image.

The code I wrote for this is:

```
$(function() {
    $('.section').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass('section' + (i + 1));

        if($('.section' + (i + 1)).children('.section-image').length === 1){
          $('.section-image').addClass('span_12');
        }
        else if($('.section' + (i + 1)).children('.section-image').length === 2){
          $('.section-image').addClass('span_6');
        }
        else if($('.section' + (i + 1)).children('.section-image').length === 3){
          $('.section-image').addClass('span_4');
        }
        else {
          $('.section' + (i + 1)).children('.section-image').addClass('span_3');
        }

        if(!$('.section-image').hasClass('span_12')){
          $('.section-image').last().addClass('col_last');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that it applies the first if (span_12) and the last else (span_3) to each section with an image. For example it displays it as:

```
<div class="section-image col span_12 span_3">
```

I have tried other methods but I can't get it to look into one section at a time and apply the classes correctly.

What I am trying to do is if the jQuery looks in the first .section and there's one image then apply a .span_12 class to it, or if there are two images then apply .span_6 to each, and so on e.g.

```
<div class="section-image col span_12">
```

or

```
<div class="section-image col span_6">
<div class="section-image col span_6 col_last">
```

If anyone can offer advice on this I would be really grateful.

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833678/count-number-of-img-tags-inside-a-div-tag, to count number of images in a div using jQuery. And I think once you get the right count of images then you can resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. To apply a span_ to each

```
$('.section-image').addClass(function(){
return ["none", "span_12", "span_6", "span_4", "span_3"]
   [$(this).parent().children('.section-image').length];
 });
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference `$('.section' + (i + 1))` before it's had a chance to add that class. Also, it's generally bad practice to create the same jQuery object over and over in the same function because grabbing that info from the DOM is an expensive operation. Instead, assign it to a variable: `var thisSection = $('.section' + (i + 1));`. Since it's inside the `.each()`, you can just use `$(this)`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.section').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass('section' + (i + 1));

        if($(this).children('.section-image').length === 1){
          $('.section-image').addClass('span_12');
        }
        else if($(this).children('.section-image').length === 2){
          $('.section-image').addClass('span_6');
        }
        else if($(this).children('.section-image').length === 3){
          $('.section-image').addClass('span_4');
        }
        else {
          $(this).children('.section-image').addClass('span_3');
        }

        if(!$(this).find('.span_12')){
          $('.section-image').last().addClass('col_last');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Taytorious. Thanks for the reply! I have tried your suggestion of using a var but it still does the same, with it adding both span_12 and span_3 in the same <div>